# Magento 2: passing parameters from controller to phtml view

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

There's a way to passing parameters from controller to phtml view using PageFactory class?

Controller code:

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use MyModule\Services\Service\CurlService;

class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{

protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $curlService;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    CurlService $curlService
) {
    parent::__construct($context);

    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->curlService = $curlService;
}

public function execute()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == true)
    {
        $response = json_decode($this->curlService->response());
        switch($response->status)
        {
            case 'ok': $msgReturn = 'Successfull'; break;
            default:   $msgReturn = 'Error'; break;
        }
    }
    
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu(static::MENU_ID);
    
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Page Title'));
    
    return $resultPage;
}
```

I need passing $msgReturn using PageFactory to the corresponding view

Answer (score 0):

To add data to your phtml block, simply enter this example in the controller where you set your data.

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

$page = $this->pageFactory->create();
$block = $page->getLayout()->getBlock('block_alias');
$block->setData('name_var', $data);
```

And then in the phtml file

```
$data = $block->getData('name_var');
```

Comment: following your instructions, i'm getting this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData()"

Comment: Did you add the class in the constructor and then run the compile? Are you calling the right block? Do you have any other errors while debugging? Are you loading the block? The method I described is magento core.